# How to get exit status of shell commands [run through system()] in C?

Tags: c, command-line

I have a `C` code that executes some commands on the shell. The code is something like this:

```
int main(){
           int x=0;
           x=system("some command");
           printf("Exit Status:%d\n",x);
           return 0;
}
```

The problem here is upon failure I get some other values than the exit values into x.

Suppose if we execute `xyz` on `bash` it exits with status=127 as the command is not found or 1 if the command exists and fails. How do I get this 127 or 1 into my `C` code.

Comment: BTW, `system()` doesn't use bash, it uses `/bin/sh`. Thus, tagging this question "bash", or using "bash" in the title, is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use (on Linux at least) the macros related to [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)

```
int x = system("some command");
if (x==0) 
   printf("command succeeded\n");
else if (WIFSIGNALED(x)) 
   printf("command terminated with signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(x));
else if (WIFEXITED(x)) 
   printf("command exited %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(x));
```

and so on. Read more about [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html). Beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) when passing to `system` some runtime-generated string.